# A question about algebraic normal number

Tags: analysis, number-theory

We have all heard about the famous question posed by Borel : is every irrational algebraic number, normal? 
The question has the reputation of being far-reaching and the answer is not known even for $\sqrt 2$. Furthermore, we do not know whether $\sqrt 2$ is rich or even whether each digit occurs infinitely many times in its decimal expansion. 
Denote the set of irrational Algebraic numbers by$ IALG$ and denote the set of numbers that every digit appears infinitely many times in their decimal expansion by $DECINF$. my question is: has anybody yet proved $DECINF \cap IALG \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: Sorry, but what $\phi$ means here? Note that $0.(1234567890) \in \text{DECINF} \cap \text{ALG}$.

Comment: @AlgorithmsX Then the question is strangely easy: $\phi \in \text{DECINF} \implies 10 \phi \in \text{DECINF}$. (And strictly speaking, $\text{DECINF} \cap \text{ALG} \subset \mathbb{R}$ while $\phi \in \mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: The definition of [normal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) is more restrictive than asking for each decimal digit to occur infinitely many times.

Comment: @Abstraction Sorry I edited the question. The number should be irrational. This is a very weak version of Borel's conjecture.

Comment: @AlgorithmsX And sorry again for my bad notation, it has nothing to do with the golden ratio. It means the empty set.